# Configuring reverse proxy with mod_proxy rules using only .htaccess file

Tags: web-server, .htaccess, web-hosting, web

I am trying to connect website (which is share hosted) to a remote server, so that when I access `http://example.com/test/` it will display the results from `http://remote-example.com/` (which is a web app server)

The web hosting provider only allows me to modify the `.htaccess` file for configuration, they said mod_proxy is enabled and it can be configured with the `.htaccess` file.

They linked me [Apache's Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html), but I haven't been able to get it to work. 
The hosting provider is using Lightspeed as the web server.

Is someone able to give me an example of what the `.htaccess` file should look like?

Can a reverse proxy be configured by modifying the `.htaccess` file only?

Comment: @MrWhite I've tried using `ProxyPass /test http://remote-example.com` and 
`ProxyReverse /test http://remote-example.com` But it didn't make any difference. Maybe the `proxy_http` module is not enabled

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297233/how-to-rewrite-location-response-header-in-a-proxy-setup-with-apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion with the hosting provider and further research into the issue I've concluded it cannot be done, due to the host restrictions.

The apache documentation itself specifies that `ProxyPass` can only be used in the `Context: server config, virtual host, directory`

Here is a link to some useful information which might help others [Can ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse work in htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808506/can-proxypass-and-proxypassreverse-work-in-htaccess)

Comment: Did you try using mod_rewrite's `RewriteRule` with the `P` flag? This allows mod_rewrite to route requests through mod_proxy and is the only way you'd be able to do this in a shared environment, without access to the server - which appears to be what your host is suggesting. (Then again, this still might not be sufficient. Then again, if it's not then why has your host enabled mod_proxy in the first place?)

Comment: @DocRoot they have rewrite and mod_proxy enabled but its still cannot be done under their current system

Comment: `RewriteRule [P]` corresponds to `ProxyPass`, but it doesn't implement `ProxyPassReverse`. I'm not sure it is possible to implement its behavior in `.htaccess` - you need to rewrite the `Location` response header.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, as long as you have the ability to rewrite the HTML that comes back from the origin server. I've been able to create a working reverse proxy for WordPress hosted on a shared server where I don't have access to the Apache configuration.

See: [My comments in response to a similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205092/how-to-set-up-proxy-in-htaccess/)

Note: Proxied pages are noticeably slower.